How do I use an html or jsx file (string) from the api with React or NextJS?
I have a NextJS project, admin page is available. On the admin page, there is data from my application and I can edit this data, a data that I can edit is an object related to the home page, htmlBody. I fill this htmlBody value with an html editor (ck editor etc.). But I can only fill html, what I want is to paste a react component into this editor as it is and use it in react. I want to import and use this value from the api.
I couldn't do anything, my boss wanted such a system

If you want to handle a jsx that's coming from the api in your code, you can use HTMLReactParser to convert that data to string. This is the example from my usage of it
  import HTMLReactParser from 'html-react-parser';
             <div>
              {data?.historyText && HTMLReactParser(data?.historyText)}
            </div>

Here is the documentation
